# Avoiding browser auto-underlining and linking generic words

Tags: css

I've seen this all over the net in all browsers: the dreaded blue link on highly searched works.

Currently, on my site at http://www.thumbslinger.com down in my bird-seed 'legal' copy, the two words "play guitar" are getting underlined and linking. In Firebug, I inspect and find this automatically inserted:

```
<a id="FALINK_2_0_1" class="FAtxtL" href="#">play guitar</a>
```

I had to get around Yahoo and their thing about randomly selecting generic words that showed up in searches when coding emails but besides overriding this particular ID, is there any talk on a way to keep this from happening in the first place?

EDIT: Now I see there are two other words and they are given unique ID's! Not as easy to just restyle the FALINK. I can use jquery to parse and search but ye gods.. what is all this?

Comment: I never realised this was an automated thing not added by site creators, so a +1 for educating me with your question

Comment: Most probably a third-party ad script. Nefarious things.

Comment: Luckily, it doesn't seem to change with refreshes so I guess there actually is one time when using !important is somewhat ok!

Comment: Umm... if this were specific to one or two sites, I would agree with BoltClock that it's a script on their site, but if it's across the net I'm guessing you have some malware. This is **certainly** not something that any of the major browsers do of their own accord.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like some kind of software in your own computer, though probably not something classified as malware by virus protection tools.

Searches for strings like fatxtl and falink mostly give results where markup containing them appears as visible texts in discussion forum and blog postings (and one hit on an “Experts Exchange” site, where the “approved answer” is just a vague guess about “search hijack virus”).

However, there are pages where code with constructs like `<a class=FAtxtL href=... id=FALINK_1_0_0 ...>` appear in markup. Perhaps the software that generates links like the one you saw, in your own browsing (not on the web page) is really meant to inject links, with real URLs and not `"#"`, into documents that might get uploaded.

Running some virus protection and anti-adware software is a good idea anyway. Even though they might not recognize this kind of software by name, they might detect it by its properties.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I discovered something called YonToo that was installed. Once I removed it, the links stopped and so did a dropdown thingy that started appearing recently when I was on Amazon. No idea where YonToo came from, but I deleted it from applications and that solved the unwanted links and who knows what else

Comment: Installed in your browser, or on your website? The original question is about such text on the asker's website.

Comment: It would be software installed on your computer. For me it was something called PureLeads. It's uninstaller didn't work quite right either so I had to manually remove the rest of the files

Answer (score 0):

Hey I just wanted to update this post as I found the exact cause that others may come across. It's actually called FBPhotoZoom which can come to a browser via Facebook and usually, one also has EasyInline found here: http://www.easyinline.com/support

that page above will tell you how to turn it off but essentially, check your browser extensions for the FBPhotoZoom and disable it...if that is not there, it could have been installed so check your control panels/add/remove programs and look for it there.

Very annoying for me and of little value in the end so I'm not sure where I picked that up, but it's nice to have found the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

DealCabby is another one that does this.

I had no idea this was external ad-ware, I thought it was added by developers who liek to annoy their viewers :)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I just wanted to add something that I found as well in case someone from the future runs into this:

My browser was underlining random words and a popup on hover would appear showing an add for TopArcadeHits.

It turns out TopArcadeHits software was actually installed on my machine and a plugin was created in my browser.

I'm 99% certain this came from downloading something from CNET.

Just something to look out for.

Answer (score 0):

I had TopArcadeHits installed on my system, but also had an AddOn installed in my FF browser. The giveaway was that the popup add that appeared on mouseover said "powered by TopArcadeHits".

I uninstalled the program and disabled the AddOn (I think there may have also been a plugin), and the problem disappeared.